# Как сменить надпись у двух кнопок с одинаковым классом?

Tags: javascript

Имеется код, который меняет надпись у кнопки. Как сделть, что-бы он менял надпись у 2-х и более кнопок у которых имеется одинаковый class ?

```
new MutationObserver( Mutations => {
      for (let Mutation of Mutations) {
        for (let Node of Mutation.addedNodes) if (Node instanceof HTMLElement) {
          if (Node.matches('.button')) Node.innerHTML = 'Моя кнопка';
          else {
            let el = Node.querySelector('.button');
            if (el)  el.innerHTML = 'Моя кнопка';
          }
        }
      }
    }).observe( document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
    
    <div class='button' id='button' >Кнопка</div>
    <div class='button' id='button1' >Кнопка1</div>
```

Comment: querySelectorAll + forEach - получить все, перебрать, заменить у каждой содержимое

Comment: Arbery 11, этот комментарий мне совсем не поможет. Я же чайник ) Нельзя ли пример кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получить все кнопки `querySelectorAll`, перебрать полученное `forEach`, заменить у каждой на нужное содержимое `innerHTML`.

```
new MutationObserver( Mutations => {
      for (let Mutation of Mutations) {
        for (let Node of Mutation.addedNodes) if (Node instanceof HTMLElement) {
          if (Node.matches('.button')) Node.innerHTML = 'Моя кнопка';
          else {
            let els = Node.querySelectorAll('.button');
            if (els.length > 0) {
              els.forEach(item => {
                item.innerHTML = 'Моя кнопка';
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }).observe( document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
    
    <div class='button' id='button' >Кнопка</div>
    <div class='button' id='button1' >Кнопка1</div>
```

Comment: Arbery, работает как надо. Большое спасибо!